# Button sometimes has IsPointerOver = true after popup closed

Tags: xaml, button, win-universal-app

In a UWP app, I have a button that opens a popup by binding to it's IsOpen property.  When the popup opens, I want the state of the button to look like it's still selected, so I set the style of the button to a new style in the onClick event for the button.  When I close the popup, I set the style of the button back to the original style.

About 30% of the time, when the popup closes, the button has IsPointerOver set to true, so the button looks like the mouse is over it, when it isn't.  Moving the mouse over and then off the button restores it back to it's unselected state.  How can I do this in code?  IsPointerOver is read only, so I can't reset it that way

Comment: Is that after you closed the popup, the mouse just stay on the button? What's the way you close the popup?Do you use the same button open and close the popup?

Comment: The mouse is nowhere near the button when the popup closes - I think it might be a xaml bug.  I closet he popup by setting isOpen to false